# Apply JavaScript function to multiple elements

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm building a website and I'm adding a image zooming thingy with CSS3 and JavaScript.

Now this works perfectly, until you have more than one image. So what I'm looking for is a better system that achieves the same results. I've tried a couple of things but it keeps coming back to having JavaScript code that works for all the images but zooms each one individually.

`.contentimgleft` and `.contentimgleftl` are the same except for the `width` and `height`. So I'm hoping there is some way to just change these two styles to individual images with the same JavaScript code?

Also note that the is a class for right floated images as well but I omitted them for simplicity as they are exactly the same.

```js
function image() {
  if (document.getElementById("img").className.match(/(?:^|\s)contentimgleft(?!\S)/)) {
    document.getElementById("img").className = "contentimgleftl";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("img").className = "contentimgleft";
  }
}
```

```css
.contentimgleft {
  float: left;
  margin: 5px 5px 5px 10px;
  background-color: #888888;
  width: 25%;
  height: 25%;
  transition: all .4s linear;
}

.contentimgleftl {
  float: left;
  margin: 5px 5px 5px 10px;
  background-color: #888888;
  width: 97%;
  height: 98%;
  transition: all .4s linear;
}
```

```html
<img id="img" onclick="image()" class="contentimgleft" src="https://via.placeholder.com/800x300">
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IDs are unique, although there is nothing to stop you using the same ID more than once in a document. However, if you have a duplicate ID then `document.getElementById("img")` will *usually* return the first one - see [behavior of javascript getElementById() when there are elements with duplicate IDs in HTML DOM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11528731/behavior-of-javascript-getelementbyid-when-there-are-elements-with-duplicate-i). So your code will only ever be manipulating the *first* `id="img"` element, no matter which one is clicked.

So you should remove the `id` attribute or have different `id` attribute values for each image. I doubt that you really need an `id` so in my example below they have been removed.

If the `id` is removed, there needs to be a way of making the `image()` function work on the `img` that is clicked. JavaScript has (at its core) the concept of [**scope**](http://www.digital-web.com/articles/scope_in_javascript/) which we can use to make each function execute on the correct image.

One way to do that is passing the argument `this` to the `onclick` function to access the HTML element that is handling the event - see [How does the "this" keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/javascript-this-keyword)

**HTML**

```
<img onclick="image(this)" class="contentimgleft" src="http://lorempixel.com/50/50/abstract/1"/>
<img onclick="image(this)" class="contentimgleft" src="http://lorempixel.com/50/50/abstract/2"/>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function image(img) {
    if (img.className.match(/(?:^|\s)contentimgleft(?!\S)/)) {
        img.className = "contentimgleftl";
    } else {
        img.className = "contentimgleft";
    }
}
```

[**see demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/EZXsB/)

To answer the CSS question, yes you can declare the duplicate properties once and depending how you do it, you might need to change the way the JavaScript is matching class names.

If all the `<img>` elements require the same style, simply use

```
img {
    float: left;
    margin: 5px 5px 5px 10px;
    background-color: #888888;
    width: 25%;
    height: 25%;
    -webkit-transition: all .4s linear;
    -moz-transition: all .4s linear;
    -o-transition: all .4s linear;
    -ms-transition: all .4s linear;
    transition: all .4s linear;
}
.contentimgleftl {
    width: 97%;
    height: 98%;
}
```

But if you want, you can use another CSS class for the common properties, for example

```
.zoomable {
    float: left;
    margin: 5px 5px 5px 10px;
    background-color: #888888;
    width: 25%;
    height: 25%;
    -webkit-transition: all .4s linear;
    -moz-transition: all .4s linear;
    -o-transition: all .4s linear;
    -ms-transition: all .4s linear;
    transition: all .4s linear;
}
.contentimgleftl {
    width: 97%;
    height: 98%;
}
```

with the following change to the HTML

```
<img onclick="image(this)" class="zoomable" src=""/>
```

However, the JavaScript would need changing to *add* or *remove* the `contentimgleftl` class rather than replace the `img`'s className, because if you just replace it, you will lose all the `.zoomable` style.

["hasClass" with javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5085567/hasclass-with-javascript-or-site-with-jquery-to-javascript-translation), [How do I add a class to a given element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/507138/how-do-i-add-a-class-to-a-given-element), 
[Remove CSS class from element with JavaScript (no jQuery)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155737/remove-css-class-from-element-with-javascript-no-jquery) might be useful if you decide to use that approach.

Comment: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html#link4 might help explain the `this` keyword in this scenario - "If you want to use this for accessing the HTML element that is handling the event, you must make sure that the this keyword is actually written into the `onclick` property"