# loop javascript function for each row after add new row

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a row in a table that can be duplicated by javascript. In the first row I have a javascript code that makes a calculation.

After duplicating a new row the calc javascript is not working for the new row..

What i do wrong?

table row:

```
<table class="Parameter" id="new">
    <form action="ProjectParameterNewRecord.php" method="post">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="Parameters" name="TypeOfOut" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <?php include "ExchangeRates.php"?>
            </td>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input id="Cost" type="number" value="" class="ee105" name="Cost" onchange="changeCost()">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input id="Amount" type="number" value="" class="ee105" name="Amount" onchange="changeAmount()">
            </td>
            <td><span id="minisum" name="minisum" onchange="changeminisum()"></span>
            </td>
            <td id="system">
                <input type="hidden" id="ParameterID" name="ParameterID"></input>
            </td>
            <td id="system">
                <input type="hidden" id="ProjectID" name="ProjectID" value="3"></input>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit">
            </td>

    </form>
    </tr>
</table>
```

code to create a new row:

```
        <script>
    var counter = 1;
    jQuery('img.add-author').click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        counter++;
        var newRow = jQuery(' <tr class="Parameters" id="AA"><td><input type="text" id="Parameters" name="TypeOfOut"/></td><td><select id="Unit" type="text" value=" " class="ee105" name="Unit" onchange="changeUnit(this.value)"><option value="2">KM</option><option value="4">euro</option><option value="3">$</option><option value="25">WorkHour</option><option value="3">dollar</option><option value="25">WorkHour</option> </select</td></td><td><input id="Cost" type="number" value="" class="ee105" name="Cost" onchange="changeCost()"></td><td><input id="Amount" type="number" value="" class="ee105"  name="Amount" onchange="changeAmount()"></td><td><span id="minisum" name="minisum" onchange="changeminisum()"></span></td><td id="system"><input type="hidden" id="ParameterID" name="ParameterID' + counter +'"></input></td><td id="system"><input type="hidden" id="ProjectID" name="ProjectID" value="3"></input></td><td><input type="submit" value="Submit"></td></tr>');

        jQuery('table.Parameter#new').append(newRow);
    });


    </script>
```

javascript code to calculate:

```
function CalcUnitValue() {
    var U = document.getElementById("Unit").value;
    var SUM = -1 * ((((($('#Amount').val())) * (((($('#Cost').val())) * (($('#Unit').val())))))));
    document.getElementById("minisum").innerHTML = SUM;
    document.getElementById("minisum").readOnly = true;
}

function changeCost() {
    var C = document.getElementById("Cost").value;
    var SUM = -1 * ((((($('#Amount').val())) * (((($('#Cost').val())) * (($('#Unit').val())))))));
    document.getElementById("minisum").innerHTML = SUM;
    document.getElementById("minisum").readOnly = true;
}

function changeAmount() {
    var C = document.getElementById("Amount").value;
    var SUM = -1 * ((((($('#Amount').val())) * (((($('#Cost').val())) * (($('#Unit').val())))))));
    document.getElementById("minisum").innerHTML = SUM;
    document.getElementById("minisum").readOnly = true;

}

function changeUnit() {
    var C = document.getElementById("Amount").value;
    var SUM = -1 * ((((($('#Amount').val())) * (((($('#Cost').val())) * (($('#Unit').val())))))));
    document.getElementById("minisum").innerHTML = SUM;
    document.getElementById("minisum").readOnly = true;

}

function minisum() {
    var SUM = -1 * ((((($('#Amount').val())) * (((($('#Cost').val())) * (($('#Unit').val())))))));
    return alert(document.getElementById('minisuminput').innerHTML);
```

thank you :)

Comment: it seems as if a large chunk of your code is missing? Where is the opening `<tr>` tag? Also, at first glance I am going to guess that your issues are being caused by id redundancy. ID's for elements have to be unique on a page. When you are creating new elements, you are setting the ID to _AA_ on everything. And all of your javascript seems to use `.getElementById()` which will cause issues.

Comment: Wow... never seen so many unneeded parenthesis before `((((($('#Amount').val())) * (((($('#Cost').val())) * (($('#Unit').val())))))))` You can remove at least 7 (pairs) of them! In fact, I think they can all be removed without affecting the calculation there :)

Comment: CalcUnitValue, changeCost, changeAmount and changeUnit are all identical, apart from the first line in each where you set a variable which is then never used.  Get rid of three of those four functions, the unnecessary variable, and the unnecessary parentheses as @TrueBlueAussie pointed out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Your HTML is invalid. You have an extra closing `</td>` in the middle. You also need to put the `form` outside the `table`.
- You can't have duplicate IDs in a HTML page and expect to reference anything except the first one. Use classes instead.
- Don't use inline event handlers with jQuery. Use delegated jQuery handlers if you have dynamically added elements.
- Use an element hidden in the page to hold your template. If you store it in the HTML, and not code, you would have noticed your `</select>` was missing and replaced by an extra `</td>`.
- You mix JavaScript selectors with jQuery. Just stick to jQuery selectors. They are shorter.
- None of the extra parenthesis are required for `a * b * c * d` equations.
- `inputs` and `img` elements are meant to be self-closing, not have end tags.
- All your calculations are exactly the same, so reuse the code.
- Get into the habit on using consistent case (upper/lower/mixed) for variables and classes.

Use delegated event handlers like this:

```
$(document).on('change', '.cost,.amount,.unit,.parameters', function() {
    var $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    var sum = -1 * $('.Amount', $tr).val() * $('.cost', $tr).val() * $('.Unit', $tr).val();
    $(".minisum", $tr).html(sum);
}
```

**Re templating:** you can store your template row in a dummy `script` block, with unknown type (I use `text/template`) and it will be ignored by the browser.

e.g.

```
<script id="template" type="text/template">
<tr class="Parameters" id="AA">
  <td>
    <input type="text" class="Parameters" name="TypeOfOut" />
  </td>
  <td>
    <select class="Unit ee105" type="text" value=" " name="Unit">
      <option value="2">KM</option>
      <option value="4">euro</option>
      <option value="3">$</option>
      <option value="25">WorkHour</option>
      <option value="3">dollar</option>
      <option value="25">WorkHour</option>
    </select>
  </td>
  <td>
    <input class="cost" type="number" value="" name="Cost">
  </td>
  <td>
    <input class="amount ee105" type="number" value="" name="Amount">
  </td>
  <td><span class="minisum" name="minisum"></span></td>
  <td class="system">
    <input type="hidden" class="ParameterID" name="ParameterID{counter}" />
  </td>
  <td class="system">
    <input type="hidden" class="ProjectID" name="ProjectID" value="3" />
  </td>
  <td>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </td>
</tr>
</script>
```

You will note a `{counter}` placeholder where you wanted to insert a new value. Use it as the HTML source to create new rows.

e.g.

```
$('table.Parameter#new').append($('#template').html().replace('{counter}', counter));
```

**JSFiddle to play with ( most of this functional):** https://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/33e9ptgu/

Comment: who i print this:
$(".minisum", $tr).html(sum); 
into input value?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your problem is coming from having duplicate ids.  When there are duplicate ids, the behavior of `document.getElementById()` is undefined.  Each browser will try to do something reasonable, but there's no way to know which element will be returned (though it's [usually the first element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11528731/behavior-of-javascript-getelementbyid-when-there-are-elements-with-duplicate-i)).

One option is to change the duplicated ids to `class`, and then when creating a new row, give the row it's own unique id using your counter:

`var newRow = jQuery(' <tr class="Parameters" id="' + counter + '"><td>.....</td></tr> ');`

This will allow you to access whichever row you want for calculation, as well as it's children [using jquery](http://www.mkyong.com/jquery/difference-between-find-and-children-in-jquery/):

Instead of `$('#Cost')` or `document.getElementById("minisum")`, use 
`$('#' + [number of rowid]).find('.Cost');` or `$('#' + [number of rowid]).find('.minisum');`

A couple of other tips:

- To get the value of an `<input>` into your functions, simply pass it as a parameter like so: `onchange="changeCost(value)"`.  Now you can delete 3 of your 4 identical functions as well as remove the first line of the remaining one.
- You don't need closing `</input>` tags (see [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_input.asp))
- There are two `</td>` tags on your second column
- Make sure you have correct tag nesting on your `</tr>` and `</form>` tags