# Reference a confirmation window from forloop

Tags: javascript, python, django

I've been trying to create a popup delete confirmation overlay from a forloop. I can't make it work or define which ids or how to pass identifiers for the overlay.

I got this, but it only refers the first element of the loop. I tried serialize the ids with the element pk (myNavRef{{ref.pk}}), but doesn't work

```
{% for ref in perf_bim.referenciapredio_set.all %}
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">{{ forloop.counter }}</th>
        <th>{{ref.rol_fk.rol}}</th>
        <th>{{ref.rol_fk.dir}}</th>
        <td><a href="{% url 'det_ref_pr' ref.pk %}"><img src="{% static 'arrow.png' %}" height=20 alt=""></a></td>
        <td><button onclick="openNavRef()" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark btn-sm"><img src="{% static 'trash.svg' %}" alt="" height=15 ></button><br></td>

    </tr>

    <div id="myNavRef" class="overlay">
        <div class="fontformat"style="padding-top:250px;width:40%;margin:auto;">
            <div class="overlay-content">
                <a href="{% url 'borrar_ref' ref.pk %}"type="button "class="btn btn-warning btn-sm"style="color:black;">Eliminar Referncia de Predio Rol: {{ref.rol_fk.rol}}</a>
                <br>
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" type="button "class="btn btn-bright btn-sm" onclick="closeNavRef()">Cancelar</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}

<script>
    function openNavRef() {
        document.getElementById("myNavRef").style.display = "block";
    }
    function closeNavRef() {
        document.getElementById("myNavRef").style.display = "none";
    }
</script>
```

thanks!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [behavior of javascript getElementById() when there are elements with duplicate IDs in HTML DOM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11528731/behavior-of-javascript-getelementbyid-when-there-are-elements-with-duplicate-i)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display the corresponding `div` then you can define the div with `unique` id. Then you can show corresponding `div` with the provided `id` of the element.

First set your `div` element with unique `id` as

```
<div id="myNavRef{{ref.pk}}" class="overlay">
```

Then on your `button` element `onclick` pass the same `id` as

```
<button onclick="openNavRef('{{ref.pk}}')" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark btn-sm">
```

Also for your close button as

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" type="button "class="btn btn-bright btn-sm" onclick="closeNavRef('{{ref.pk}}')">Cancelar</a>
```

Then in your `javascript`

```
<script>
    function openNavRef(id) {
        document.getElementById("myNavRef" + id).style.display = "block";
    }
    function closeNavRef(id) {
        document.getElementById("myNavRef" + id).style.display = "none";
    }
</script>
```